# capturing events for dynamically loaded controls

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Lets say I have a container, some method will add multiple children to this container, I want to be able upon double click event to know which one is being double clicked and get a reference to it. I don't have access to the controls, they just exist on the container Children Collection after they got loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would perhaps be to call `InputHitTest` in an appropriate event handler. You would of course have to implement the double click, as there is no such thing in WPF Panels.

```
private void Container_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var container = (UIElement)sender;
    var hitElement = container.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(container));

    Trace.TraceInformation("Hit Element: {0}", hitElement);
}
```

Comment: sorry may be my question wasn't clear , I don't have the control at Design time , the control is created and loaded after that

Comment: This is still working, the control is your dynamic created control. The MouseMoveHandler will be used for all dynamic created controls.

Comment: see the edited question, I got your point, that is what I'm doing to other types of controls , they got initiated on control variable and then added to the collection, but those I'm searching now doesn't pass by the control variable , they just got injected there in my container collection, I want to be able to treat them also like the ones pass by the variable control